# What is this electric diagram symbol?

Tags: identification, symbol, diagram

What is this electric symbol found on an MCC-related electric single line diagram? It looks like a voltmeter with some sort of resistor but it would make more sense if it was an actuator I think.

[image]

On some other places there is only the V symbol which probably is just a voltmeter:

[image]

Comment: My first thought was 0-900V VOLTMETER but I'm not sure about the box on the LH side of it.

Comment: yes, I added a snipshot of a similar symbol without the box this time.

Comment: Can you go to the actual equipment and have a look?

Comment: @AndrewMorton that is sadly not an option

Comment: Since there is no capacity (kVA) rating on the transformer, I would suspect it is for metering.  Are there any protective relays or other devices that would need a 0-110V voltage input signal?

Comment: not particularly

Answer (score 2):

This symbol [image]

- does not seem to be adopted by [modern standards](https://control.com/textbook/electric-power-measurement-and-control/single-line-electrical-diagrams/) for **"Single-Line" Power grid Drawings**.
  Rather now it looks a like a voltmeter symbol with an attachment.
  Delta generators might not be earthed, but Y neutral generators would be earthed. This might give some clue.

[image]
[image][image]